# Problem with tkinter checkbutton and class

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some problems with Checkbutton in classes. They always return the start value.
I am attaching the example code, in Main.py I create a window and a button to invoke my class with the checkbutton. In this second class (WindowProteins.py:) the check button does not work and always returns the same value

Main.py:

```
#tkinter import
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

import WindowProteins as wPr

#font
font_title = ('times', 18, 'bold')
font_subtitle = ('times', 14, 'bold')

def CreateProteins():
   windowPr = wPr.ProteinsWindow()
   windowPr.mainloop()

#create welcome window
def CreateWelcome():
   #window
   global window_welcome
   window_welcome = tk.Tk()
   window_welcome.geometry("400x300")  # Size of the window 
   window_welcome.title('Main')
   #button
   btn_proteins = tk.Button(window_welcome, text='Proteins', 
      width=20,command = lambda:CreateProteins())
   btn_proteins.grid(row=2,column=1)

   window_welcome.mainloop()  #Keep the window open

CreateWelcome()
```

WindowProteins.py:

```
#tkinter import
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

class ProteinsWindow(tk.Tk):
  df = pd.DataFrame()

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    # configure the root window
    self.title('Proteins')
    self.geometry('800x400')

    #fonts
    self.font_title=('times', 18, 'bold')
    self.font_subtitle = ('times', 14, 'bold')
    self.font_base = ('times', 11)

    #Protein FDR checkboxes
    self.var_chc_low = IntVar(value=1)
    self.chc_low = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='Low',variable=self.var_chc_low, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=self.agreement_changed )
    self.chc_low.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='w')
    self.chc_low.select()

  def agreement_changed(self):
     print(str(self.var_chc_low.get()))
```

how can i solve?

Comment: You have multiple instances of `Tk()` here - an explicit one in `CreateWelcome()`, and as the base class of `ProteinsWindow`.  One of the numerous problems caused by this is that Tkinter Vars don't work right.  Use `Toplevel` instead as the base class for your second window.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am quite new to python, could you explain better what you mean please?

Comment: you should use `tk.Tk()` only to create main window. Other windows you should create using `tk.Toplevel()`. And you should use only one `mainloop()` because two loops can make conflict when you try to get value.

Comment: shorter: `command=CreateProteins` without `lambda` and without `()` (and without spaces around `=` - see more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) )

Comment: Perfect now everything works, thank you very much! If you create an answer I can accept it

Comment: i do it in main:
**def CreateProteins():
    windowPr = wPr.ProteinsWindow()**

and it in protein:
**class ProteinsWindow(tk.Toplevel):**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `tk.Tk()` only to create main window. Other windows you should create using `tk.Toplevel()`. And you should use only one `mainloop()` because two loops (and two main windows) can make conflict when you try to get value.

---

Working code (as single file) with other changes

You may use `BooleanVar()` and `True/False` instead of `IntVar()` and `1/0`

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
import pandas as pd

# font
font_title = ('times', 18, 'bold')
font_subtitle = ('times', 14, 'bold')

# --- classes ---  # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames`

class ProteinsWindow(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.df = pd.DataFrame()
     
        # configure the root window
        self.title('Proteins')
        self.geometry('800x400')

        # fonts
        self.font_title = ('times', 18, 'bold')
        self.font_subtitle = ('times', 14, 'bold')
        self.font_base = ('times', 11)

        # Protein FDR checkboxes
        self.var_chc_low = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
        self.chc_low = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='Low', variable=self.var_chc_low, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, command=self.agreement_changed)
        self.chc_low.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.chc_low.select()

    def agreement_changed(self):
        print(self.var_chc_low.get())

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names`

def create_proteins():
    window_pr = ProteinsWindow()

def create_welcome():
    """Create welcome window."""
    
    # window
    global window_welcome
   
    window_welcome = tk.Tk()
    window_welcome.geometry("400x300")  # size of the window 
    window_welcome.title('Main')
    
    # button
    btn_proteins = tk.Button(window_welcome, text='Proteins', width=20, command=create_proteins)
    btn_proteins.grid(row=2, column=1)

    # keep the window open
    window_welcome.mainloop()  

# --- main ---

create_welcome()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)